# The form cannot be rendered. This may be due to a misconfiguration of the Microsoft SharePoint Server State Service. For more information, contact your server administrator. 

Tags: infopath, 2007

```
  I am getting the error when i want to open the infopath forms of sharepoint library in a browser.  The error is:
```

"The form cannot be rendered. This may be due to a misconfiguration of the Microsoft SharePoint Server State Service. For more information, contact your server administrator. "

Can any one have an idea How to overcome the above error......?

Comment: Is your State Service Application up, running and configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On the Taskbar, click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Windows PowerShell Modules.
2. In Windows PowerShell, create a service application by typing $serviceApp = New-SPStateServiceApplication -Name “State Service”
3. Create a State Service database and associate it with a service application, by typing New-SPStateServiceDatabase -Name ”StateServiceDatabase” -ServiceApplication $serviceApp.
4. Create a State Service Application Proxy and associate it with the service application by typing New-SPStateServiceApplicationProxy -Name ”State Service” -ServiceApplication $serviceApp -DefaultProxyGroup.